# Vue JS - Getters return the object instead the actual value in the store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, getter

I am unable to get the customer 'dad' in my store using getters. But, it shows on the screen the objects like this `[ "dad" ]`. How am I supposed to correct this?. I am a newbie to vue.js

```
<template>
          <div class="hello">
        <p>{{ GET_CUSTOMERS }}</p>
        </div>
        </template>
    <script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    export default  {
    computed:{
      ...mapGetters([
      'GET_CUSTOMERS'
      ])
    }
    </script>
```

My store

```
state: {
            customers: ['dad']
        ],
getters: {
GET_CUSTOMERS(state){
                return state.customers;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `customers` data is an array. When you render an array directly in a template like `{{ ['dad'] }}`, Vue will render it in the DOM as `[ "dad" ]`.

I take it you want to render just one customer? You can render the first customer like this:

```
{{ GET_CUSTOMERS[0] }}
```

To render each customer, you will need to loop over each customer using `v-for`:

```vue
<ul>
  <li v-for="(customer, i) of GET_CUSTOMERS" :key="i">
    {{ customer }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, if you prefer, you can just join each customer into a single string with each customer separated by a comma:

```
{{ GET_CUSTOMERS.join(', ') }}
```